# Почему не ставится тире перед "это"?

Tags: тире, сказуемые, подлежащее

Предложение такое: ***Первое, что меня поразило, это пассажиры*** (Б. Акунин, 2010).

Вроде бы по правилам перед ***это*** (в предложениях такой структуры) всегда ставится тире, а здесь его нет. А вы бы какой знак поставили?

Это нормированная пунктуация или авторская?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

**Грамматический разбор**

***Первое*** – субстантивированное слово в роли подлежащего, к нему относится придаточное определительное предложение.

***Пассажиры*** – сказуемое.

***Это*** – слово-связка  между подлежащим и сказуемым.

Comment: тире не всегда ставится. Вот ссылка. https://fb.ru/article/171594/tire-pered-eto-kak-pravilno

Comment: Серж, спасибо за ссылку, я ее просмотрела, но своего варианта не нашла. В статье делается вывод: Итак, ставится ли тире перед «это», если речь не идет об авторских знаках, почти полностью зависит от того, о какой части речи и о какой синтаксической роли этого слова идет речь.  В моем примере всё чётко: "это" является связкой в простом предложении между подлежащим и сказуемым. Это именно связка, а в статье  рассматривается много других вариантов с "это", но только не этот. А вы ее сами читали, может быть, я не заметила.

Comment: Хотя... да, тире нужно. Просто интиутивно тире ставить не хочется. Но, наверное, нужно. Первое - это пасажиры, что меня поразило.

Comment: Серж, если убрать определительное придаточное, то да, надо ставить тире. Значит, оно оказывает влияние.  Там смысл такой. Герой плывет на круизном лайнере и очень страдает от качки. Когда море успокоилось, он наконец смог разглядеть сам корабль, его пассажиров и описать свои первые впечатления. Он мог бы написать так: Что меня больше всего поразило? Первое - это пассажиры.

Comment: Ну да. Первое, что меня поразило, - это пассажиры.

Answer (score 4):

Думаю, что дополнительное тире здесь не требуется. Здесь не просматривается "сквозное" выражение тождества (первое - это пассажиры), поскольку имеется смысловая часть между *примыкающими* частями высказывания:

> Что меня поразило, [так] это пассажиры. [Это *первое, что меня
>   поразило*]

Тире потребовалось бы при другом порядке слов и оттенках:

> И вот что меня поразило: первое - это пассажиры, второе - ....

Comment: Alex_ander, спасибо за ответ.   По поводу тождества. Тождество (в моем понимании) мы имеем тогда, когда предмет и признак взаимообратимы в любой ситуации, например: Москва – столица России. Столица России – Москва. В других случаях признак характеризует предмет. Если мы говорим о впечатлениях, то предметом является впечатление, а пассажиры признаком. Если мы рассказываем о пассажирах, то впечатление становится признаком. В нашем случае первый вариант, и там всё должно быть по правилам. Тире ставится между подлежащим-предметом  (впечатление) и сказуемым-признаком (пассажиры) при наличии связки.

Comment: Кстати, тире можно поставить: Первое, что меня поразило, – это пассажиры. Тогда это будет классически правильный вариант. Удивительно то, что и по смыслу, и по интонации пауза/тире не кажутся обязательными. Здесь что-то другое. Такое впечатление, что смысловым центром является вторая часть, а первая приобретает характер вводности. Можно предположить, что здесь ИНВЕРСИЯ подлежащего и сказуемого (по образцу: "славные люди соседи мои"), тогда тире может не ставиться. Но я считала, что такое возможно только при отсутствии связки.