# «Ведь то, что письма совпадают, это не проблема». Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение

Я любитель ставить лишние знаки препинания, и мне хочется видеть вторую запятую в этом предложении, чтобы более явно выделить кусок между запятыми. Это верно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ведь то, **что письма совпадают**, это не проблема.*

Запятая действительно ставится, то есть придаточное предложение обособляется с двух сторон.

**Дополнительное пояснение**

Здесь сложнее определить **грамматику** предложения и объяснить, почему перед ЭТО дополнительно не ставится тире. Похожая тема уже  разбиралась на форуме: [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461083/Почему-не-ставится-тире-перед-это](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461083/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE)

Я полагаю, что это **СПП с местоименно-определительным придаточным**, но в особом варианте.

Сравнить:  *Ведь не проблема то, что письма совпадают.*  Это классический вариант (ТО, ЧТО) с придаточным на втором месте.

Однако такой вариант неудобен, поэтому придаточное ставится на первое место, но при этом в главной части используется **указательно местоимение ЭТО** (в данном случае ЭТО не является словом-связкой между подлежащим и сказуемым,  поэтому и нет тире).