# Помогите определиться со знаками препинания в предложении

Tags: запятые

Но всё что вижу я это то до чего могут дотянуться мои глаза.

Comment: Ваши варианты?--

Comment: Три варианта: 1) Но всё, что вижу я — это то, до чего могут дотянуться мои глаза. 2) Но всё, что вижу я, это то, до чего могут дотянуться мои глаза. 3) Но всё что вижу я, это то, до чего могут дотянуться мои глаза.

Comment: Какие варианты правильные, можете подсказать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос непростой, жаль, что его, вероятно, закроют.

(1) Стандартная конструкция со связкой ЭТО: *Но **всё**, что вижу я, — **это то,** до чего могут дотянуться мои глаза.*

Но она не очень хороша и графически, и фонетически, хотя в принципе тоже возможна, если нужно подчеркнуть паузу. В конечном счете многое зависит **от контекста.**

(2) *Но **всё**, что вижу я, это **то**, до чего могут дотянуться мои глаза.*

Я бы оформила предложение по этому варианту. Это местоименная связь в сложноподчиненном предложении, местоименная пара ***всё — то***. В этом случае ЭТО имеет значение указательного местоимения, а не связки. Увеличенной паузы тоже нет.

Конструкция достаточно частотная, и на форуме обсуждалось **похожее предложение без тире.** Например: Первое, что меня поразило, это пассажиры (Б. Акунин). [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461083/Почему-не-ставится-тире-перед-это](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461083/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE)

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (о запятой после "всё")

Запятую придется поставить, так как сочетание нельзя приравнять к устойчивому обороту. У Розенталя есть пример: ***достать что нужно*** (но: достать ***всё, что нужно***) http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146

**Примечание.** Я понимаю, что сочетание "всё, что вижу" хотелось бы прочитать без паузы, но соотношение между частями предложения определяется не только паузами, но и ударением. Читается это примерно так (мы стараемя выделить логическим ударением те части предложения, которые сопоставляются):

*Но всё, что **вИжу** я, это **тО**, до чего могут дотянуться мои **глазА**.*

Comment: Sharon, а что вы видите непростого в этом вопросе? Разве что сама постановка, автор говорит о запятой в единственном числе. И до обсуждения тире (соверешенно, имхо, здесь избыточного априори) ему вообще расти и расти. А так-то это уровень средней школы.  И почему жаль, что закроют?

Comment: Здесь воможны варианты, вот что непросто.  ЭТО может быть связкой, а может быть указательным местоимением.   Также можно обсудить "всё что вижу" в качестве устойчивого выражения.  Вот и жаль, если закроют. Интересно было бы послушать обсуждение. Вопрос не кажется мне домашним заданием,  скорее всего , он составлен  участником самостоятельно.

Comment: Не вижу тут реальных вариантов. Но даже если они есть, аскер о них не спрашивает. Его интересует только запятая, причем именно в единственном числе.

Comment: А мне показалось, что все варианты как раз обозначены. Тире поставлено в первом варианте, запятая после ВСЁ ставится или не ставится. Разные сочетания.

Comment: Если бы он реально спросил о тире, ничего против вопроса я бы не имел, хотя и дал бы отрицательный ответ. не нужно оно там изначально. Но судя по всему, это все высоты, совершенно ему ненужные и недоступные... Впрочем, не смею препятствовать. Обидно только, что  мы все дальше уходим от правила "домашних заданий".

Comment: А, он успел исправить свое пояснение (в комментариях под вопросом) по поводу вариантов. Уже после того, как я ответил. Ну тогда ладно, не буду более придираться. Но про тире все равно не понимаю. Надумано оно тут изначально.

Answer (score 0):

***Но всё, что вижу я, это то, до чего могут дотянуться мои глаза.***

Фраза сама по себе неряшливая (зачем тут инверсия "вижу я" вместо "я вижу"?), но если говорить о пунктуации, то только так. Все знаки очевидны и никакой факультативности тут не просматривается.
Оговорюсь, что если фраза вырвана из стихотворного источника, то это отдельный разговор, здесь я этот случай не рассматриваю.

Поскольку в обсуждении появились какие-то варианты по тире, объясняю, почему оно здесь невозможно в принципе.

Есть только два актуальных случая, когда наличие "это" предопределяет обязательное наличие или отсутствие тире.

> § 166. Тире ставится перед *это, это есть, это значит, вот*, если
> сказуемое, выраженное *существительным в именительном падеж*е или
> неопределенной формой, присоединяется посредством этих слов к
> подлежащему, например: Коммунизм – это есть Советская власть плюс
> электрификация всей страны.

Требование "сказуемое выраженное существительным в именительном падеже" невозможно применить к нашей фразе, у нас есть только местоимение, к тому же совсем не очевидно, что оно является само по себе сказуемым (это отдельный вопрос). Тире как обязательный знак не рассматривается.

Второй случай - про "это" в качестве подлежащего, в этом случае тире однозначно не нужно, но это вообще не про нас.

Ну еще есть много случаев, когда тире факультативно или предопределяется авторским пониманием. Но такие варианты обычно не приводятся как правильные без оговорки их факультативности. Такие интонационные тире можно вставить почти в любое место фразы, где автор предполагает паузу, нет смысла разбирать каждый случай. Иное приводило бы к изрядной путанице, что видимо, и произошло у Sharon.